# velodyne_rawscan md5sum missmatch

Tags: pointcloud, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am trying to get velodyne rawscan from a input bag which publishes velodyne_common/RawScan (topic= velodyne/rawscan) but I get this error,

Waiting 0.2 seconds after advertising topics...

```
[ERROR] [1308039369.255405494]: Client [/my_3D_to_2D] wants topic /velodyne/rawscan to have datatype/md5sum [velodyne_common/RawScan/a36da642742ddd79774fbc755f9c5cdd], but our version has [velodyne_common/RawScan/d34cf5a37a401b668e53c57f6409eb76]. Dropping connection.
```

Please help me.

Edit:
I am playing the bag and trying to subscribe the topic /velodyne/rawscan in a program and print the subscribed input on stdout, but I get the errer and even after using "rostopic echo /velodyne/rawscan" while playing bag I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] [1308109245.015874373]: Client [/rostopic_13899_1308109244719] wants topic /velodyne/rawscan to have datatype/md5sum [velodyne_common/RawScan/a36da642742ddd79774fbc755f9c5cdd], but our version has [velodyne_common/RawScan/d34cf5a37a401b668e53c57f6409eb76]. Dropping connection
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10232/velodyne_rawscan-md5sum-missmatch/) by [ravi](https://answers.ros.org/users/624/ravi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-06-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your problem is that you have a bag file with different message versions than the code you are running.  Usually the bag files were recorded in a past version of ROS and are incompatible.  You should be able to use [rosbag fix](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Commandline#fix) to fix the bag files.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0